# Is apt-get install method the same as Ubuntu software centre installation?

Tags: installation, apt, software-center

I usually use Ubuntu software centre to install programs but I sometimes use `apt-get install` instead. Is the Ubuntu software centre method just a user interface equivalent of the `apt-get install` commands? I use Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: It is that. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware

Comment: @Elfy You might want to make that an answer (perhaps slightly expanded).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a difference between installing an application via Ubuntu Software Center or a terminal?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/120774/is-there-a-difference-between-installing-an-application-via-ubuntu-software-cent)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Except for paid apps as [tachyons](https://askubuntu.com/users/39372/tachyons) has [pointed out](https://askubuntu.com/a/166250/22949) (which can be installed and uninstalled with `apt-get` but only *once purchased* in the Software Center), the Software Center is primarily a front end for the *various `apt-` commands*--not just `apt-get`. For example, the Software Center will also search for packages and let you edit your Software Sources.

The main *practical* distinction between the two is that the Software Center will automatically fetch information about what packages are available from where and in what versions. In contrast, when installing or upgrading software with `apt-get`, you should run `sudo apt-get update` first if you haven't done so recently. `sudo apt-get install ...` does not (ever) cause `sudo apt-get update` to be run automatically (though it may be run automatically up to once a day as part of automatic updates in the system).

Comment: I downloaded zoom application and installation went well with `dpkg -i <pacakge>` but program was not launching. later I uninstalled this package and installed the same file via  'software install' application, then it worked , why it so ?

Answer (score 5):

Yes , software center is just a gui front end of apt , but paid apps and some of the free apps which is submited through my apps portal are not available in apt-get

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  As is another popular program - synaptic.  I find synaptic faster.

Comment: No idea why this got downvoted - software centre is slow.

Comment: Because the software center is not intented to be a replacement for Software Center. You can't really compare the two.

Comment: That makes no sense, and even if you meant to say synaptic, it still isn't relevant in the context of the OP's question.

Comment: @Cumulus007 You can't compare the Software Center and Synaptic, but you *can* compare the Software Center and `apt-get`? Most of the functionality of all three programs overlaps. People choose consciously which of the three to use all the time, when any of the three (or others) would work.