# Can I install items on Ubuntu, without using the command line?

Tags: installation, software-center

Everything I've googled so far has used the command line?

Comment: Use **Ubuntu Software Center** to search for and install programs/apps.

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu comes with a handy tool called the Software Center. With this tool, you can install any software program from the Ubuntu Archives. It is a [kind of](https://askubuntu.com/questions/166247/is-apt-get-install-method-the-same-as-ubuntu-software-centre-installation?rq=1) frontend to `apt`, the command line tool usually used to manage packages.

A quick tour:

[image: Ubuntu Software Center logo]

You can open it from the side bar or search "Software Center" from the Dash.

Once opened, you can easily search for the software you want. I'll pick on Clementine for an example.

[image: Searching for sotware]

If you see the software you want, you can either click "More Information" to see user reviews of the software, related software, and the developer's description; or if you like just click "Install".

[image: More Info/Install]

I wanted to know what some of the features of this media player are, so I clicked "More Info".

[image: More Info]

What's more, you can use the buttons at the top to see installed software and your history.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty easy, open the **"Ubuntu Software Center"**:

Click on the top right icon, then in the search field, write `soft`
an the **"Ubuntu Software Center"** icon will appear, click on it and you open the Graphic Interace to search and install Ubuntu applications.

[image]

And for adding package with the graphic user interface,
from the **"Ubuntu Software Center"**:

- click on `Edit` | `Software Sources`
- in the child window, click on tab `Other softwares`
- then `Add` in the bottom of the window.

[image]

Comment: How about packages downloaded from the internet?

Comment: @tmyie see for adding a package, I edited my asnwer

Comment: @tmyie: .deb packages will install with the software center on double click. But you should refrain from installing packages downloaded from the internets while new to Ubuntu. You may not be able to repair your system on your own in case one of those packages broke it.

Comment: @tmyie, Please add this information to your question if you need help with installing a specific application that you can't get from the Software Center. Every software is different.

Answer (score 1):

There is 2nd graphic user interface: from the [the Ubuntu website](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/)

For example, if you want to install [Skype](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/) [image: Install me-tv]

[image]

To install, click on this icon, it will open the Software Center

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As well as the other answers, if you go to the **website of the software** you are trying to install, they often supply a **`.deb` file** for you to download.

This will **launch the software centre** when executed and install your software.

An example of this is on the [google chrome website](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/index.html#eula)