# Using Terminal commands in Ubuntu

Tags: command-line

Since I am a new Ubuntu user and I am not familiar with commands and Terminal is it possible to use Ubuntu like other OS without messing around with command lines, just installing apps and using them like some average user.

Comment: For practical everything that can be done with the terminal, there is a GUI option as well. The reason many solutions on AU are in command line is that it works precisely and gives you very accurate and usable information if something goes wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really you can use the ubuntu software center. With one click an app will be installed, it is very easy, no terminal required at all. But I recommend learning the terminal too. Actually at the beginning I hated it. But once you get familiar with it, it will be your friend. Get the book LinuxFund from here http://linux-training.be/downloads/

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation. I downloaded the Linux Training, and I can say it was just the thing that I needed.

Comment: That book will teach you better,You may using windows,so it is normal to hate terminal,let me tell you example if you want to create following folder ~/Music/Blues/BSB how many mouse clicks will use?? You can do it easily in terminal >> mkdir -p ~/Music/Blues/BSB 

Thats what im talking about..don afraid....

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu is a Linux distribution putting great effort in providing exactly what you asked for.

The main philosophy behind the Unity desktop environment is to provide a user experience making usage of the OS possible without deeper knowledge of computional science, and without the need to use a command line or a configuration file editor to get around with our daily tasks.

From my own experience with my **children** and with my **elderly** parents this goal is achieved to the best. Both, my kids, and my parents do not even know how to open the terminal but they are happily using Ubuntu for e-mail, internet acess, graphics editing, listening to music or video, gaming, and more.

Configuring the system is done by graphical tools from the *System Settings* menu. Adding new software can easily be done using the [Ubuntu Software Center](https://askubuntu.com/questions/341876/can-i-install-items-on-ubuntu-without-using-the-command-line), and even deeper configuration tasks can be made with the graphical **dconf-editor** (also read "[How can I configure Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29553/how-can-i-configure-unity)" for more options).

Having said this, of course there are use cases where just typing a single-line terminal command will do the same, and there are still special cases where we do not have a graphical frontend for some applications that only run from the command line. That is why support channels often just recommend a terminal command which usually works identical between distributions and Ubuntu versions, and which is easy to post in a support request.

But this is nothing we should have to be doing regularly. It is the exception we may hopefully not need when something on your system was broken. In this case somebody with a deeper knowledge of the OS, or a help channel such as Ask Ubuntu will provide you with the necessary commands you need. This is not much different to any other OS, only that help and support from the Ubuntu commmunity is usually very fast, globally accessible 7/24, and it is **free**.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation and taking your time to answer. I find this info very useful.

Answer (score 0):

It took me a long time to completely migrate from Windows to Linux.... Unfortunately Linux is not as mature as Windows with regards to GUI implementation. I suppose thats the difference between open source and proprietary. However, for day to day tasks like web browsing, emailing, watching movies and writing documents it is every bit as good. I, for one, am a convert. I dived in and started using the command line where ever possible and have not looked back since. I would strongly recommend you build a test machine from some old hardware you might have, or setup a virtual machine, and start to play with the command line. It is surprising how quickly your knowledge will grow.