# What is the difference between installing software from terminal or via software center?

Tags: apt, software-installation

I recently switched to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64-bit and I installed many essential softwares the  terminal by using this command:

`sudo apt-get install <package_name>`

Is there any difference in installing softwares through terminal or via software center (i.e. does the actual working of installation varies)?

Comment: You'll still need to define "manually".

Comment: @Pa1 do you mean by manually: software center or dpkg

Comment: @kamil both ,i.e I thought both are same the only difference is that software center provide from thrusted publisher .am I right ?

Comment: @Pa1 No. software center is different from apt-get when having troubles: http://askubuntu.com/questions/120774/is-there-a-difference-between-installing-an-application-via-ubuntu-software-cent

Comment: Not an answer, but I'll add that you probably see directions indicating to use apt-get rather than a GUI because a) the experienced users who write these directions are comfortable with it, and b) the directions are clear ("type exactly this") instead of depending on a potentially changing GUI which requires some typing and some clicking on UI elements

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are some differences:

- Using a GUI interface, installation error messages are hidden and they just give you a general message that it didn't work, but when you install something from terminal using `apt-get`, you will see all the messages that are generated; this information can be used to fix the errors.
- `apt-get` will inform you by other associated packages that are recommended along with your package.
- `apt-get` inform you by any packages that were installed previously and that are probably not needed any more.

Answer (score 2):

I guess if you can handle terminal it is much better to install software from it.You get list of packages, download speed, error messages, all kinds of useful info. But if you are a novice better stick to Software center.No big difference in process.