# How to install Thunderbird with Terminal

Tags: mail

How to install Thunderbird using Terminal?
I don't want to download from Ubuntu Software

Comment: `sudo apt install thunderbird`  which would install `thunderbird | 1:91.8.0+build2-0ubuntu1          | jammy            | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, s390x` on my current box.  You didn't provide any release details, but you'd get the appropriate version available for your *unstated* Ubuntu product.  It's also available as *snap* package which has different versions available.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a difference between installing an application via Ubuntu Software Center or a terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/120774/is-there-a-difference-between-installing-an-application-via-ubuntu-software-cent)

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Answer (score 0):

In terminal type `sudo apt install thunderbird`. Then it will ask for your password. Make sure to do `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` first. If that doesn't work (22.04) you have to add the mozilla repositorio first (`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-security/ppa`), then update and upgrade then thunderbird. 
Another way is to download the `.deb file` from the mozilla page, go to your downloads, rightclick and choose `open terminal here` and type `sudo apt install name of the .deb file`.

Comment: `thunderbird` is the Ubuntu repos, there is no need to add a ppa. It's in main, updates, and security.

Comment: OK, I thought that because Firefox is not anymore, Thunderbird would be neither. Thanks.